# app is alive but stops consuming messages after a while

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

spring-kafka consumer stops consuming messages after a while. The stoppage happens every time, but never at the same duration. When app is no longer consuming, in the end of the log always I see the statement that consumer sent LEAVE_GROUP signal. If I am not seeing any errors or exceptions, why is the consumer leaving the group?

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.4.RELEASE
spring-kafka:2.1.8.RELEASE
org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.2
```

I've set logging as
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=INFO

other settings

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=5
spring.kafka.listener.type=single
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=record
spring.kafka.listener.poll-timeout=10000
spring.kafka.consumer.heartbeat-interval=5000
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=50
spring.kafka.consumer.fetch-max-wait=10000
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.security.protocol=SSL
spring.kafka.consumer.retry.maxAttempts=3
spring.kafka.consumer.retry.backoffperiod.millisecs=2000
```

ContainerFactory setup

```java
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> recordsKafkaListenerContainerFactory(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(listenerCount);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeoutMillis);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckOnError(false);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(60000L);


        return factory;
    }
```

Listener configuration

```
@Component
public class RecordsEventListener implements ConsumerSeekAware {

    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(RecordsEventListener.class);



    @Value("${mode.replay:false}")
    public void setModeReplay(boolean enabled) {

        this.isReplay = enabled;
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${event.topic}", containerFactory = "RecordsKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void handleEvent(@Payload String payload) throws RecordsEventListenerException {

        try {
           //business logic
        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOG.error("Process error for event: {}",payload,e);

            if(isRetryableException(e)) {
                LOG.warn("Retryable exception detected. Going to retry.");
                throw new RecordsEventListenerException(e);
            }else{
                LOG.warn("Dropping event because non retryable exception");
            }
        }

    }

    private Boolean isRetryableException(Exception e) {

        return binaryExceptionClassifier.classify(e);
    }





    @Override
    public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {

        //do this only once per start of app
        if (isReplay && !partitonSeekToBeginningDone) {
            assignments.forEach((t, p) -> callback.seekToBeginning(t.topic(), t.partition()));
            partitonSeekToBeginningDone = true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onIdleContainer(Map<TopicPartition, Long> assignments, ConsumerSeekCallback callback) {
        //do nothing
        LOG.info("Container is IDLE; no messages to pull.");
        assignments.forEach((t,p)->LOG.info("Topic:{}, Partition:{}, Offset:{}",t.topic(),t.partition(),p));
    }

    boolean isPartitionSeekToBeginningDone() {

        return partitonSeekToBeginningDone;
    }

    void setPartitonSeekToBeginningDone(boolean partitonSeekToBeginningDone) {

        this.partitonSeekToBeginningDone = partitonSeekToBeginningDone;
    }
}
```

When app is no longer consuming, in the end of the log always I see the statement that consumer sent LEAVE_GROUP signal.

```
2019-05-02 18:31:05.770 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator x.x.x.com:9093 (id: 2147482638 rack: null)
2019-05-02 18:31:05.770 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Using older server API v0 to send HEARTBEAT {group_id=app,generation_id=6,member_id=consumer-1-98d28e69-b0b9-4c2b-82cd-731e53b74b87} with correlation id 5347 to node 2147482638
2019-05-02 18:31:05.872 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Received successful Heartbeat response
2019-05-02 18:31:10.856 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Sending Heartbeat request to coordinator x.x.x.com:9093 (id: 2147482638 rack: null)
2019-05-02 18:31:10.857 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Using older server API v0 to send HEARTBEAT {group_id=app,generation_id=6,member_id=consumer-1-98d28e69-b0b9-4c2b-82cd-731e53b74b87} with correlation id 5348 to node 2147482638
2019-05-02 18:31:10.958 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Received successful Heartbeat response
2019-05-02 18:31:11.767 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator x.x.x.com:9093 (id: 2147482638 rack: null)
2019-05-02 18:31:11.767 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Using older server API v0 to send LEAVE_GROUP {group_id=app,member_id=consumer-1-98d28e69-b0b9-4c2b-82cd-731e53b74b87} with correlation id 5349 to node 2147482638
2019-05-02 18:31:11.768 DEBUG 9548 --- [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | app] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=app] Disabling heartbeat thread
```

[Full log](https://gist.github.com/rabiddroid/83a99d685ca3e4a1bc8e005e5351456d)

Comment: I added the [apache-kafka] tag since I don't think this has anything to do with spring. `>Using older server API v0` - what is your broker version?

Comment: I believe you would receive this message if (1) the consumer was closed or (2) the consumer didn't rejoin in time after a rebalance due to the `max.poll.interval.ms` elapsing. Do the logs indicate any of these?

Comment: @GaryRussell, the broker is handled by another team. They said it is 0.10.01.

Comment: @frankgreco, I've added more of the logs as link to a gist. Please let me know if you are seeing the behaviour 2 in the logs. Also to clarify, the max.poll.interval.ms is the same as spring.kafka.consumer.heartbeat-interval, which the client sets when talking to broker?

Comment: No it's a kafka consumer property - it's the maximum time allowed between `poll()`s. Your listener MUST exit within this time (default 300000ms). See [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread), which was added to the 0.10.1.0 broker. You can set it with `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=...`. I see nothing obvious in the gist; ask them to look at the server logs for the same timeframe.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. I am going to see if I can get them to look in their logs. Also since their broker is older (0.10.0.1), correct me if wrong, I am thinking, the property spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.poll.interval.ms=... may have no effect and I should probably look into solutions specified in KIP-62 `The options for the user at the moment to handle this problem are the following:
*Increase the session timeout to give more time for record processing.
*Reduce the number of records handled on each iteration with max.poll.records.`

Comment: You said the version was `0.10.01` which I assumed was a typo (01 Vs. 1) but you're saying the typo was the missing `.`. So, yes, it could be the session timeout that's the issue (but I would expect to see messages about a rebalance in that case). But it's been a looooong time since I've used such an old broker - you really should encourage them to upgrade to a much newer version. The current Kafka version is 2.2.0. 0.10.0.1 is ancient.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who replied. Turns out, it was indeed the broker dropping the consumer on session timeout. The broker a very old version (0.10.0.1) did not accommodate the newer features as outlined in [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread) that spring-kafka version we used could make use of.
Since we could not dictate the upgrade to the broker or changes to session timeout, we simply modified our processing logic so as to finish the task under the session timeout.

Comment: How did you identify that the broker dropped the consumer?